# PHP code will not echo out the attribute of my object

Tags: php, class, echo, setter, getter

I am working on a lab for class and having a little trouble getting my echo statement to function properly. I am trying to store a sentence in a variable within an object and then retrieve and echo the value of that variable.

```
 <?php
class MagicSentence {
    public $sentence;

    public function __construct($sentence) {
        $this->setSentence($sentence);
    }

    public function getSentence() { return $this->$sentence; }
    public function setSentence($sentence) {
        $this->sentence = $sentence;
    }
} // End class MagicSentence

    $magicSentence = new MagicSentence("The cow jumped over the moon.");
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Pete's Treats Candy Contest</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php 
            //include ('header.php'); 

            echo 'The magic sentence is: ' . $magicSentence->getSentence();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Comment: Thank you for the link. I should have mentioned that I was pretty sure I was having a syntax problem. I tried rearranging the code several times and double checked over the code samples I studied.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the effort, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
public function getSentence() { return $this->sentence; }
```

Notice the missing `$` on `sentence`. Just one of those things about PHP to remember.

Comment: Thank you, that was a sharp eye!